# UICollectionViewCell position wrong after animating

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

So I'm trying to build an open source library combo between Shazam Discover and Tinder based on a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

**I'm having an issue where, after animating a cell the the side (e.g. swiping it away to the side), the cell will stay in that position when it is being reused by the `UICollectionView`. (I'm guessing that cell reuse is the issue here since it only seems to happen after scrolling a couple of cells)**

Is there any simple way to fix this behavior? Or am I doing something else wrong here? Been looking at it for a couple of days but can't seem to find a fix myself.

**You can try/check out the code on [Github](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper/tree/development)**

I tried posting some code snippets but I'm not sure which ones I should post here since it's a lot of code. If I should post code on here, let me know.

Any help is much appreciated. Have a nice day :)

*Here's a demo of what's happening:*

[image: demo of what' happening]

Comment: How do I trigger that throw away animation? I downloaded the project but there is not swiping away working..

Comment: Just swipe (drag from the center to one side) the swipes are still a bit buggy too, but swiping to the left side should work the best

Comment: @MilanNosáľ also make sure you're downloading the code from the development branch because master doesn't include this code yet.

Comment: yep, I just noticed I used master.. gonna check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the cell class, in `HomeVC`, where you handle panning to swipe the card away you manipulate also the layer's `anchorPoint` - you need to reset that to make drawing work as before:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    // reset to default value (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint)
    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}
```

Comment: @JoniVR I have created a pull request with the fix, you just needed to reset the anchorPoint, since you manipulated it during panning.. moreover, notice the weird glitch when swipe up/down is very short and fast.. something to debug too, but it's not related to this question... I don't have time now to contribute to that right now, but maybe later I can get to it :)..

Comment: I merged it already, I know, there's still lots of work in order for it to be stable, but this has helped a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoniVR I'm glad I could contribute to open source :)